# Agregar información al EXIF de una imagen

Tags: python, linux

Hay muchas librerias para obtener y algunas para modificar la información EXIF de imágenes JPG y TIFF.
Por ejemplo con `Pyexiv2` se puede leer y modificar exif con el siguiente codigo:

```
import pyexiv2
metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata('prueba.tif')
metadata.read()
print metadata.exif_keys
```

y para modificar, por ejemplo la hora se puede hacer lo siguiente

```
metadata['Exif.Image.DateTime'].value = datetime.datetime.today()
metadata.write()
```

Pero no he podido encontrar alguna libreria con su codigo para poder AGREGAR información al EXIF de una imagen TIF.

Hay una que se llama `Piexif` que copia un exif de una imagen JPG a otra, de la siguiente forma:

```
from PIL import Image
import piexif
piexif.transplant('imagen1.jpg', 'imagen2.jpg')
```

Pero necesito hacerlo con imágenes TIF, por lo cual no sirve. Exactamente son como 10 tag que hay que agregar, pero con estas librerias solo se puede leer y modificar.